# Scroll down all (vertical) scrollable bars whatsoever with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, loops

In latest Chrome I would like to automatically scroll down all scrollable items lists in webpage.
Instead scrolling down the *scrolling item* inside the *scrolling item container* until the *downmost tip* to expose more items (and repeat this action in each scrollable list to expose all items in it), I'd like to run a vanilla JavaScript function to maximally scroll down everything for me until the *downmost tip*.

These seem to me methods one should consider:

**1)** `window.scrollBy(0,500);`
**2)** `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);`
**3)** `element.scrollIntoView();`

### I tried:

```
const [...elements] = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)
});
```

> undefined

and:

```
const [...elements] = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.scrollIntoView();
});
```

> undefined

How can one loop through all (vertical) scrollable bars whatsoever and automatically and maximally scroll down all of them, at once, with vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close.

You just need to use each element's `scrollHeight` instead of always using the body's.

```
const [...elements] = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
elements.forEach((element) => {
    element.scrollTo(0,element.scrollHeight)
});
```

Comment: Thx. Seems I should repeat that with a `window.setInterval` for some 30 seconds (and than cancel it somehow) to get the maximal amount of content in each list.

Comment: this should scroll directly all elements all the way. Unless the elements are not yet populated or unless the scroll triggers js scripts that will modify the page and create more scrollable space.